# Show only time in jquery datetimepicker but store the full date at backend

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mongodb, datetimepicker

I have a requirement where I need to allow the users to select only the time in an input box using datetimepicker. I achieved this by adding below code in my angularjs controller:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: '', 
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm z', 
        timeOnly: true,
        showTimezone: true,
        timezone: "+0100"
    });
```

But, I need to store the complete ISOdate in the mongodb. How can this be done? The date can be the current date appending the input time by the user. for e.g. user input time is : **08:00 z** then, it should be converted to **2016/06/01 08:00 z**

Below is my HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="templateFormData.selectDateTimePicker" id ="datetimepicker1" ng-focus = "showDateTimePicker()" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" ng-required="true"/>
```

Comment: Date will be always current date?

Comment: @titi23 : yes it will always be the current date.

Comment: Refer [DATE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on how to achieve it. Also try searching here for similar questions before asking. There will be some solutions already.